# Как добавлять, удалять, редактировать записи в таблице JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, table

Как с помощью JQuery создать список или таблицу со следующими функциями:

- Добавлять новые записи в список или таблицы
- Удалять уже существующие записи
- Редактировать существующие записи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как динамически добавлять или удалять строки внутри таблицы с помощью
>   jQuery?
>
> Используйте метод jQuery `.append()` или `.remove()`
>
> Вы можете использовать метод jQuery `.append()` для добавления или
>   добавления строк внутри таблицы HTML. Аналогичным образом вы можете
>   использовать метод `.remove()` для удаления или удаления строк таблицы,
>   а также всего, что внутри него из DOM динамически с помощью jQuery.
>   Посмотрите следующий пример.

Вот код который это делает:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Add / Remove Table Rows</title>
<style type="text/css">
table{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
table th, table td{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });
    
    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $(".delete-row").click(function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });
});    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>
            <td>Peter Parker</td>
            <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Зачем нужно было удалять ответ и создавать новый, если можно было отредактировать старый или дополнить его?

Comment: @AK Нелзя было. Кто-то влез со своим редактированием, когда я правил.